# Why can't my GWT Editor see its custom sub editor when flushing?

Tags: gwt

I have a custom GWT sub editor that I want to include as part of a working uibinder setup.  All the behavior is in tact, and all the "normal" editors (Textbox, ListBox, etc.) flush properly to the pojo.  But when I put the reference to the sub editor into the main editor and its ui.xml file and remove the fields from the primary ui.xml that are now contained in the sub editor, I get the following error:

> ui.xml has no ui:field attribute for {the field that was pushed down to subeditor and associated uibinder}

I noticed while debugging that the sub editor has the `attached` attribute as `false`.

On an application that is very similar to the one I am working on, when debugging, `attached` attribute was `true`.

I have used sub editors successfully across other projects, but for some reason the current application is acting differently and I'm trying to figure out what.

Can someone give me any recommendations on where to look to debug if my editor driver does or does not see this particular sub editor, or what "attached" on the editor means? A GWT class/method name, where the sub editors get registered, another thread, an article, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue. It turns out the field name in the sub editor wasn't liked. I moved a field as is from the main editor, which was named "fromPLA". While it worked in the main editor, when moved to the sub editor, the path didn't map the same. I tried with a a normal camel cased named field, and it worked as expected.